# How to add a preloader while content load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So on start a loader should be there and as soon as weather is shown the `preloader` should be gone.It's using `simpleweather.js`plugin.

I've tried using `.hide()` `.addClass()`.Doesn't seems to work.

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude);
  });
function loadWeather(location, woeid) {

  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h1><i class="wi wi-fw wi-yahoo-'+weather.code+'"></i></h1>';
      html += '<h2>'+weather.temp+'&deg'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';

      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
       html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li></ul>';
 $("#weather").hide().html(html).fadeIn("slow");      

    },
    error: function(error) {
  $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
   });
}

});
```

//HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="weather"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: have a look my working example below

Answer (score 0):

Only as idea:

create a loading animation in your html, it should be visible by default, so user see it directly on page visit. Then hide it on "success" in your js.

```
<div id="loading">Loading....</div>
```

and js code

```
jQuery("#loading").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to show a loader, do the following.
 Add a div with img tag which points to the loader file.

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none"><img src="<path_to_loader_file>"></div>
```

Update your function:

```
function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  var load = $('#loader');
  load.show();
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
               load.hide();
    },
    error: function(error) {
             load.hide();
    }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        $('#some-overlay-with-spinner').show();
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        $('#some-overlay-with-spinner').hide();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $('#some-overlay-with-spinner').hide();
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    $('#some-overlay-with-spinner').hide();
});
```

**UPDATE:** Try [topbar](http://buunguyen.github.io/topbar/) as progress indicator. You can show and hide it instead of an overlay with a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

```
add this code
<div id="loading">Loading....</div> // use a gif image loader within this div

$("#loading").show(); //before ajax request
```

your ajax code --here

```
$("#loading").hide(); // after ajax response
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('51.5034070,-0.1275920');
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $("#weather").html('<img src="http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif">');

  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h1><i class="wi wi-fw wi-yahoo-' + weather.code + '"></i></h1>';
      html += '<h2>' + weather.temp + '&deg' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';

      html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li></ul>';
      $("#weather").hide().html(html).fadeIn("slow");

    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="weather"></div>

</body>
```